# changing javafx choicebox whilst running background thread causes app to crash

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have a settings Window which contains two Choice boxes. One to select an audio interface, and the other to select the input channel on that interface.

When an item in the second choicebox is selected, this starts two background threads, one which opens the targetdataline and the other thread displays a meter to view the level of the audio signal.
This works fine, however when I select another audio interface on the choicebox, I want to interrupt both Threads, save the device changes and then start the threads again. Currently, doing this causes the app to hang, but no errors are reported. Any help is appreciated.

I have an object 'audio1Monitor' which synchronises the audio thread. The audio thread is started on initialisation and is in the waiting state prior to this method being called.  I think there are two or three different errors happening.  The method 'captureAudio1()' is the task to be run in the thread. This relies on the objects of each of the two choice boxes. I have saved these using Preferences API 'systemPrefs'.
The errors only occur when changing choicebox objects once the threads are running.  I essentially want to stop the captureAudio1() task and put the thread to wait, whilst the choicebox event listener executes, and then at the end notify the thread to resume and start captureAudio1(). Sometimes I get a firevaluechangedevent error, which I have read is often to do with changing the objects of a choicebox when an object is selected, so tried deselecting and clearing the list in the first choicebox listener. I am very aware I am in over my head here, and have been pulling my hair out for days.

The code for the first choiceBox:

```
chan1interface.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>(){
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            synchronized(capture.audio1Monitor){

                if (capture.audioInput1.getState().equals(RUNNING)){
                    capture.running = false;
                    try {
                        capture.audio1Monitor.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ConfigController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                } else {
                }

            Mixer.Info[] mixers = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
            Mixer m = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixers[chan1interface.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()]);
            System.out.println(chan1interface.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            Line.Info[] lines = m.getTargetLineInfo();
            for (Line.Info info : lines){
                ArrayList channels = showSupportedChannels(info);
                System.out.println(channels);
                int maxValue = getMax(channels);
                ArrayList channelList = new ArrayList();
                    for (int i=0; i<maxValue; i++){
                        channelList.add(i+1);
                        }

                chan1channel.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                chan1channel.getItems().removeAll();
                ObservableList channelListOL = FXCollections.observableArrayList(channelList);
                chan1channel.setItems((ObservableList) channelListOL);
                }   
        String chan1Interface = m.getMixerInfo().getName();
        System.out.println(chan1Interface +" - chan1 interface");
        final String Interface1 = "interface1";
        systemPrefs.put(Interface1, chan1Interface);



            }

        }
    });
```

The code for the second choiceBox:

```
chan1channel.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue){
            synchronized(capture.audio1Monitor){
                capture.running = false;
                if (capture.audioInput1.isAlive()){
                    try {
                        capture.audioInput1.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ConfigController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                }


                chan1selectedchannel = (int) (chan1channel.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()) + 1;
                Mixer.Info[] mixers = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
                Mixer m = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixers[chan1interface.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()]);
                Line.Info[] lines = m.getTargetLineInfo();
                for (Line.Info info : lines){
                    ArrayList channels = showSupportedChannels(info);
                    System.out.println(channels);
                    chan1totalchannels = getMax(channels);
                }
                final String channel1selectedchannel = "chan1selectedchannel";
                final String chan1total = "chan1totalchannels";
                systemPrefs.put(channel1selectedchannel, String.valueOf(chan1selectedchannel));
                systemPrefs.put(chan1total, String.valueOf(chan1totalchannels));


            capture.running = true;

            System.out.println("4 is called");
            capture.audio1Monitor.notify();

            if (meterUpdate.isAlive() == false){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    meterUpdate.start();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ConfigController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is the code for the audio Thread:

```
Thread audioInput1 = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        synchronized(audio1Monitor){
       System.out.println("audioInput1 thread started");
       while (constantLoop == true){
        try {

            System.out.println("audioInput1 'try' thread started");
            captureAudio1();
            System.out.println("audioInput1 Thread is waiting");
            audio1Monitor.wait();
            System.out.println("after waiting in thread");

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(audioIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(audioIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            try {
                audio1Monitor.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex1) {
                Logger.getLogger(audioIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            }
            System.out.println("after waiting in thread");
            Logger.getLogger(audioIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
    }
    }
    }
};
```

The meter thread:

```
Thread meterUpdate = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run(){
    System.out.println("meter updating");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConfigController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    while (capture.running == true){
        int chunkDivision = 5;                                              //How much to divide each chunk into (total array / chunk division = SPL ms
        double[] localSPLArray = capture.chan1double;
        double sum1 = 0;
        for (int h=1; h<(chunkDivision+1); h++){
            long meterStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Start meter = " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (int i=0; i<(localSPLArray.length/chunkDivision); i++){
            sum1 += (Math.pow(Math.abs(localSPLArray[i + (chunkDivision*h)]), 2));
        }
        double RMS1sqrt = Math.sqrt(sum1/(localSPLArray.length/10));
        double RMS1;
        if (RMS1sqrt<5){
            RMS1 = 0.1;
        } else {
            RMS1 = 20*Math.log10(RMS1sqrt/(20*Math.pow(Math.E,-6)));
        }
        long meterStop = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                double waitTime = (500/chunkDivision) - (meterStop-meterStart);
                System.out.println("WaitTime = " + waitTime);
                Thread.sleep((500/chunkDivision) - (meterStop-meterStart));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ConfigController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        Platform.runLater(() -> {

            chan1progressbar.setProgress(RMS1/90);

        });
     }
    }
});
```

Comment: Both `wait` and `notify` for `audio1Monitor` are called on the application thread. This means you'll block the application thread, which means you just pervented any event handling and relayouting from happening...

Comment: I am confused. Don't you have to be an object monitor's owner to change the state (Hence I used synchronise within the choiceBox listener). Or is this where I have gone wrong?  The application thread needs to be the one to tell the audioThread to wait from within the listener method.

Comment: I have tried removing the synchronised(audio1Monitor) from within the choicebox listener, and sure enough I get an illegalmonitorexception.  However you are correct, it seem's to be that with that with the synchronised statement left in place the app is hanging, being blocked. But this is not clear in the documentation and I have done as the it says.

Comment: The thing is: You need to ensure your methods that run on the application thread complete in a reasonable amount of time (within a few ms). If you call `wait` however the thread waits until `notify` is called which is the exat opposite of "completing in a reasonable amount of time". You need to find another way to implement this that does not involve blocking the application thread.